# How to store RoamingSettings offline?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

i was reading about windows 8 lifecycles and how it saves the user's date & stats of its apps at the suspension and termination modes , but there were a note that got me thinking it was as following :

RoamingSettings. The roaming settings app data container makes it easy to store data in a way that is accessible to the user across multiple machines. Basically, the data is uploaded to the cloud in the background for you. You can also use the local settings app data container (LocalSettings), but you should only use it when you want to store machine-specific info.

what i don't understand here do i have to store my data on the cloud to use the RoamingStettings ? what if i don't have a persisting connection , what if i want my app to store all the states data offline ?

that's my question 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you just use Roaming folder and settings without worrying about how it is done

Comment: so do you mean if i'm offline it's gonna store the data locally somewhere ? if that's the case then what this phrase means: "  Basically, the data is uploaded to the cloud in the background for you." ?

Comment: The data is stored locally in the "Roaming" folder, and the system deals with syncing to the cloud without you caring about it.  Because it is also held locally, you are guaranteed to be able to access the data even if offline.

Comment: when the system is online, it will sync roaming folder for apps. the folder is local to each system and you just read files and settings like you would from local folder. There is a file size limitation however

Comment: Thank you very much it does make a lot of sense now so it's offline stats data as long as i'm not online